Can a walrus expression be put inside square brackets rather than parentheses?
Take the following code:
k = 'A'
d = {}
d[k := k.lower()] = 'b'
print(k)
print(d)

This gives the output one would expect:
a
{'a': 'b'}

However, for similar code in a project of mine, flake8 complained about such a walrus expression being a syntax error (on a github runner for python 3.8 at least; on my computer there seemingly wasn't an issue).
So my question is whether a walrus expression always has to be within parentheses, or if cases like these are correct too.

It doesn't need to be used in square brackets nor parentheses.
For instance in an if block:
k = 'A'
if l:=k.lower() == 'a':
    print(l)

Or:
s = ' a '
if x:=s.strip():
    print(x)

PEP 572 gives some specific cases in which parentheses are required:

There are a few places where assignment expressions are not allowed,
in order to avoid ambiguities or user confusion:

Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level of an expression statement. Example:

y := f(x)  # INVALID
(y := f(x))  # Valid, though not recommended

This rule is included to simplify the choice for the user between an assignment statement and an assignment expression – there is no
syntactic position where both are valid.

Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level of the right hand side of an assignment statement. Example:

y0 = y1 := f(x)  # INVALID
y0 = (y1 := f(x))  # Valid, though discouraged

Again, this rule is included to avoid two visually similar ways of saying the same thing.

Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited for the value of a keyword argument in a call. Example:

foo(x = y := f(x))  # INVALID
foo(x=(y := f(x)))  # Valid, though probably confusing

This rule is included to disallow excessively confusing code, and because parsing keyword arguments is complex enough already.

Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level of a function default value. Example:

def foo(answer = p := 42):  # INVALID
    ...
def foo(answer=(p := 42)):  # Valid, though not great style
    ...

This rule is included to discourage side effects in a position whose exact semantics are already confusing to many users (cf. the
common style recommendation against mutable default values), and also
to echo the similar prohibition in calls (the previous bullet).

Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited as annotations for arguments, return values and assignments. Example:

def foo(answer: p := 42 = 5):  # INVALID
    ...
def foo(answer: (p := 42) = 5):  # Valid, but probably never useful
    ...

The reasoning here is similar to the two previous cases; this ungrouped assortment of symbols and operators composed of : and = is
hard to read correctly.

Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited in lambda functions. Example:

(lambda: x := 1) # INVALID
lambda: (x := 1) # Valid, but unlikely to be useful
(x := lambda: 1) # Valid
lambda line: (m := re.match(pattern, line)) and m.group(1) # Valid

This allows lambda to always bind less tightly than :=; having a name binding at the top level inside a lambda function is unlikely to
be of value, as there is no way to make use of it. In cases where the
name will be used more than once, the expression is likely to need
parenthesizing anyway, so this prohibition will rarely affect code.

Assignment expressions inside of f-strings require parentheses. Example:

>>> f'{(x:=10)}'  # Valid, uses assignment expression
'10'
>>> x = 10
>>> f'{x:=10}'    # Valid, passes '=10' to formatter
'        10'

This shows that what looks like an assignment operator in an f-string is not always an assignment operator. The f-string parser
uses : to indicate formatting options. To preserve backwards
compatibility, assignment operator usage inside of f-strings must be
parenthesized. As noted above, this usage of the assignment operator
is not recommended.


What is "the top level of an expression statement"?

flake8 complained about it being a syntax error because you were using a version of flake8 installed to a python prior to python 3.8.  it is important to match the python version you're linting against or you'll end up with false positives

disclaimer: I currently maintain flake8
